# What is an open free to use radio / music streaming service I can access via java

Tags: java, internet-radio

I am looking for a free to use radio or music streaming service which I can access using java.

I am making a game and instead of creating our own music - there must be a better alternative and hoping this coughs up with something pretty good.

Would be cool to have different music streamed to the game whilst you are playing.

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [countless](http://www.live365.com/index.live) free music streams online. [Java Sound](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html) in combination with [MP3SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) should enable you to stream most of them from your Java application.